# Probability of coin runs

Tags: probability

Say we have a coin run such that we get HHTTTH. The length of the first run corresponds to X and the length on the second run corresponds to Y. This X = 2 and Y = 3.

I want to find the probability of P(X=2), P(X=3) and P(X=2 and Y=3).

At first I thought the probability of P(X=2)=1/4 since they probability of obtaining one head is a 1/2. Then for P(X=3) I thought because out of 5 flips there are 10 possible ways to get 5 tails so 10/32 but I am not sure if this the correct method. Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: you mean P(x=2 and y=3)?

Comment: yes sorry I will edit that now

Comment: Do you keep tossing the coin until you start the third run, or do you always stop after six tosses?

Comment: I believe we continue but we re not interested in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the first run could be either heads or tails, i.e. to have a first run of length exactly $2$, the sequence must start either `HHT` or `TTH`. Each of these starts has probability $(\frac12)^3=\frac18$, because you need three coin flips to go a specific way. So overall $\Pr(X=2)=\frac14$. Similarly $\Pr(X=3)=\frac18$, $\Pr(X=4)=\frac1{16}$, etc.

After the first run finishes, you you start another run. Since all you know at this point is the first coin of the new run, and since the probability of continuing a run or ending a run doesn't depend on whether it is a run of tails or a run of heads, the probability of the second run being a particular length is the same as the probability for the first run, and also the lengths of the two runs are independent. So $\Pr(X=2,Y=3)=\Pr(X=2)\times\Pr(Y=3)=\Pr(X=2)\times\Pr(X=3)=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac18=\frac1{32}$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $P(X=n,Y=m)=\frac{1}{2^{n+m}}$